# Sending MMS and Email from within app

Tags: iphone

How does one get the pop up menu selection for email, mms etc which is used when an image is selected on the iphone.

[image: Menu]

Another thing, How can one add things to this menu e.g. facebook share, twitter share? What is the name of this menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This menu is called a UIActionSheet and you write the code that determines what is presented yourself.  Essentially you handle the tap through an actionHandler and then you can use the code below to present the menu.  You can obviously enter your own NSString for Facebook, Twitter, etc.

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle: [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"How should we do something?"]
delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle: nil 
otherButtonTitles: @"Choice 1", @"Choice 2", @"Choice 3", nil];

[actionSheet setActionSheetStyle: UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

// we need to those this in the main view otherwise the "z-order" with the tab bar takes      precedence and "covers up" the lower half of the 
// cancel button
[actionSheet showInView: [self view]];
[actionSheet release];
```

You are also able to register for a delegate notification to handle which button is tapped using UIActionSheetDelegate

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Comment: Great, thanks. How is the little reply button shown in a bar at the top?

Comment: I am not seeing a "reply button" in your screen shot or problem description?  Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: That was just a screenshot, but I would like to add my own button e.g. share where the edit image is in the image. I want to then link my own action to this button.

Comment: I am still not really clear on what you're wanting, but based on what I could understand, it sounds like you want is a UINavigationBar at the top?  In that case, you'll need a UIViewController or UINavigationController.  However, note that a UIActionSheet is modal - meaning you can't tap a button in a UINavigationBar until you dismiss the UIActionSheet that was presented.

Also, that really is a separate question, so it might be better to ask it separately.